# How to activate virtual environment in VS Code terminal for windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

> I'm using windows OS and in terminal (cmd) I created a virtual
>   environment for Django and given name as 'test'. Now I just installed
>   Visual Studio code now how to activate the virtual environment 'test'
>   in VS Code.

Comment: Have you tried reading the VS Code docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: I tried different methods. Its not getting neither error nor nor (env). If I execute any command for the project folder its showing error.

Comment: What *exactly* did you try? What was the error? What appears on the terminal? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

After moving to the project path in Pycharm just type "workon test" test will be the environment name that's it it will be done. Please update your pycharm even if you type the above command.